safari blocking query string with --blocked--
hi guys in a our web app we have a script that that looks something like
https://xxx./micro-ui.03bd673ad6dcd73520f6.js?c=nh0s2b for all browsers, except Safari version 13.1.1, 13.1.2, and 13.1.3
which loads
https://xxx/micro-ui.d872b7a72559c6275348.js?c=--blocked--?c=--blocked--?c=--blocked--?c=--blocked--?c=--blocked--?c=--blocked--?c=--blocked--
does anyone know why?
could it be with safari's  Intelligent Tracking Prevention (ITP)
